# Can I program a Raspberry Pi with Python over SSH?

Tags: python, ssh, raspberry-pi

So, I know Python, and I've been thinking of getting a Raspberry Pi, as I heard that you can program it with Python. The thing is, I don't have an extra HDMI monitor at hand, but only a Windows 10 laptop (besides, what use would an R-Pi be if you want to use it in a project, when it has to be plugged in to a monitor, mouse etc.?), so I found an alternative called SSH.  After watching a few tutorials, I'm positive that I'll be able to set up an R-Pi wirelessly with ease.  However, it still hasn't become clear to me, how I would be able to program an R-Pi with Python over SSH.

My initial goal with the R-Pi is to program it with Python, to do things like from saying "hello world", to controlling the GPIO ports, all without external hardware (except that laptop), but I haven't found anything on the internet that suits my needs.  Now, my question is, how do I do such, and to what extent will I be able to control my Pi with Python through another computer?

Thank you in advance for the help!

Comment: Yes, that's no problem at all once you have set it up. It'll be easier with console/terminal applications, the GUI will be slower/more cumbersome over the network. However, you'll have total control over the machine remotely as you would being directly connected (in fact I connect to 3 RasPis that way). ssh is the shell that'll let you connect remotely. sshd must be running on your Pi in order to accept the connection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you connect over ssh to a raspberry pi you are greeted with a terminal.

In that terminal you can use a command line editor like `nano` or `vim` to make and edit files. You can also use the command line to execute them.

In this little session I connect to a raspberry pi and then make a python program and execute it.

```
trirpi@mycomputer:~$ ssh pi@192.168.1.3
pi@192.168.1.3's password: 

The programs included with the Debian GNU/Linux system are free software;
the exact distribution terms for each program are described in the
individual files in /usr/share/doc/*/copyright.

Debian GNU/Linux comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY, to the extent
permitted by applicable law.
Last login: Mon Dec 26 17:41:02 2016 from 192.168.1.83

pi@raspberrypi:~ $ ls
projects
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ cd projects/
pi@raspberrypi:~/projects $ vim aprogram.py
pi@raspberrypi:~/projects $ python aprogram.py
```

You should learn how to use the command line so you can use commands like `cd`.

You could also setup a vnc server (I think the new raspbian image has one installed by default). That way you can also see gui's and not only a terminal.

Comment: `chmod +x aprogram.py` will let the user execute the program without explicitly invoking the interpreter, i.e., `./aprogram.py` - assuming they have `#!/bin/env python` or something equivalent as the first line in their program.

Comment: And I assume that I can use the GPIO ports the same way that a Pi with monitor mouse etc. ?